# ssh jump through a port

Tags: ssh, command-line, ssh-tunneling

I use `ssh -p 54321 john@123.4.567.89` to login a gate server and then `ssh johnaddress` to login the actual GPU server, now how do I combine these 2 commands in one using `-J`?

`ssh -J -p 54321 john@123.4.567.89 john@johnaddress` doesn't work

`ssh -p 54321 johnsmith@123.4.567.89 -J john@johnaddress`  doesn't either

Comment: The syntax is `ssh -J host1 host2` and you are using empty parameter in 1st case and just one parameter in 2nd case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man ssh_config` shows the syntax for the `ProxyJump` configuration parameter (which `-J` is a shortcut to):

> **ProxyJump**
> Specifies one or more jump proxies as either `[user@]host[:port]` or an ssh URI.

In your case it becomes:

```
ssh -J john@123.4.567.89:54321 john@johnaddress
```

or, using the configuration file's option format:

```
ssh -o ProxyJump=john@123.4.567.89:54321 john@johnaddress
```